# How would you go about dockerfile and rpm scripting?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, rpm, continuous-deployment, devops

Currently I create `rpm` for my app and install with `puppet`.  How would you go about using `docker`? Is there a best practice? What is the recommended way?

1. Continue creating rpm for your app and install in docker.
2. Just use the docker file to do the scripting you need on your image creating `rpm` for your app is not needed anymore.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself those questions:

- Do you need to audit your system (and container)?
- Do you need to know which version of application (and libraries) are installed in that container?
- Do you need to know which files were altered since installation?
- Do you need to know if files were installed from trusted source?
- Do you need to know if there is never version of app/library with security fix available for your docker image?

If you answer "No" to all those questions then just copying bits into container is perfectly fine and you really do not need rpm.
However if you answer "Yes" to some of those questions, then 'rpm' is very handy tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of connivance but we replaced rpm with docker. A docker image is  your rpm *after* it was installed by puppet into the host. It's supposed to spare you the install time on the expense of large storage (as docker images are big).

Off topic - you may find better answers at Quora where opinions are welcomed. StackOverflow it's mostly about tech answers.